# Selenium API is not working in Chrome browser

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a basic Selenium Console App in C# that opens a `URL`, signs-in and does some activity.

The code is working fine in Dev VM, but the same code isn't working in Production VM.
In Prod VM, the code just opens the URL (sign-in page) and it doesn't process anything.

I have googled and tried adding different options, but nothing worked.

```cs
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--incognito");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list");
chromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
string path = @"local Chromedriver.exe(103.0.5060.134) path";
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(path, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
driver.Url = "url";
```

I have chromedriver `103.0.5060.134`, the same as the version of the chrome browser.
Not sure what else I have to check.

The main error is:

```
[67852:69648:0818/112450.083:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

which is not happening in dev instance.
This is what I get in Production:
[image]

Chrome version
[image]

**UPDATE**

I have updated Chrome driver to `104` version and chrome browser to `104.0.5112.102` but still getting same error.
[image]

Updated Chrome version
[image]

and I have the same driver version and chrome version in dev and it is working fine. Is there a way that I can get additional logs? Not sure why exactly failing in Production.

Comment: If your chromedriver is `104` as you say, then why your log says `starting Chromedriver 103`? Have you checked on this one?

Comment: @AnandGautam, My bad I add dev version, Thanks I have added Chrome screen shot too.

Comment: One of the lines: `ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported` might be part of the problem. Maybe try `--disable-gpu` as one of the ChromeOptions?

Comment: Hello @GregBurghardt, I have added that option but still it did not work. The mail error is `[67852:69648:0818/112450.083:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101` which is not happening in dev instance

Comment: add `chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors")` to options and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, this error message...

```
[67852:69648:0818/112450.083:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

...implies that the handshake between ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser failed at some point.

---

### Details

As per [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc handshake failed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395271) the main issue is the *failure* of ***handshake*** when *ChromeDriver* handshakes with *SSL pages* in *Chrome*. Though *Chromium* team conducts test for  *SSL handshake* through *`net_unittests`*, *`content_tests`*, and *`browser_tests`* but were not exhaustive. Some usecases are left out relying on the upstream tests.

---

### Mandatory checks

Always ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).

---

### Unwanted Arguments

It's not that super clear why you need to add so many arguments. However,

- *`--incognito`*: Isn't necessary as *ChromeDriver* initiated sessions are sandboxed by default.  So you can discard it.
- *`--no-sandbox`*: Isn't needed unless your program crashes during startup being executed as a ***root*** user (***administrator***) on Linux.  So you can remove it.
- *`disable-infobars`*: It's no more effective. So you can discard it.
- *`--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list`*: Have no effect unless `--user-data-dir` argument is also present. So you can remove it.

Incorporating the above mentioned changes, you would be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for response, I have removed unwanted options and updated chrome version, ChromeDriver.exe version and Selenium Dll to 4.4.0 but still getting the same Issue. the same solution is working in dev environment. is there any system setting that I have to look? I have update my question with latest version screen shots

Comment: Is the Chrome browser getting initiated properly?

Comment: Yes, Chrome is initiating properly, Login page is opening in browser and the next step is to give username and password which is not happening in prod.

Comment: @JackFrost We can see your code trials till initialization of the Chrome browser. If that's happening you are good to go. Bluetooth adapter warnings are trivial and you can ignore them for the time being.

Comment: Actually, Chrome initiating is happening, but then after the selenium API are not working, where it should pass username and password, etc. and getting SSL error on console which is not happening in dev.

Comment: _SSL error on console_: is a trival error. We don't have a visibility to the following pass username and password steps. However, you should be fine to simulate them.

Comment: Ahh, Finally it worked after restarting Client Prod VM. Still not sure on the root cause. and Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.